# Bootstrap popper issue while using webpack

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I want to include bootstrap into my main.ts so that in _Layout.cshtml I wouldn't need to write

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

just leave

```
<script src="~/bundle/bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

When I add bootstrap (4.0.0-beta) in main.ts like this:

```
require("bootstrap");
```

I get an error in a console output

> Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)

I installed popper:

```
npm install popper
```

and added it into the plugin section, so it looks like

```
plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder]),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: node_dir + "/jquery",
                jQuery: node_dir + "/jquery",
                'window.$': node_dir + '/jquery',
                Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
            })
        ]
```

but got another webpack-script error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in
>   'D:\Projects\TestApp\TestApp.Web\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'  @
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 1:0-20  @ ./app/main.ts

Currently I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Please, double check the spelling in the question title. :)

Comment: @R.Richards haha :"-) done!

Comment: the plugins was what I was missing... so I found the answer in your question, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appeared that I need popper.js, not popper.
So to fix it:

```
npm install popper.js
```

Comment: Oh man, I spend way to much time before finding this. Thank you!